# How to read a property file present in WEB-INF from a Jar file

Tags: java

I have a jar file(an api), from which i need to load a property file which exists in WEB-INF folder. 
How do i load this property file from my jar.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it if your properties file is in `WEB-INF/classes`. In this case just write something like

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myprops.properties"));
```

Obviously the file may be located in sub folder of `classes`. In this case you have to specify  the full path when calling `getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: AlexR, This works for .properties file, but not for .xml file. Can you please let me know how do i implemets same for xml configuration file.